# What's the physical form of Monarch storyline?

Tags: godzilla, godzilla-2014, king-kong, monsterverse, kong-skull-island

Facebook page for Kong: Skull Island had [a video depicting a blurred and hard to read series of zoomed in slides from a large timeline of Monarch organization](https://www.facebook.com/KongSkullIsland/videos/485495668455520/).

One of the comments under the June 2017 video said "it sucks that we have to wait til July 18th to get a physical copy!"

As I'd like to read the slides properly, I'm trying to understand **what that physical copy the comment was referring to**. The only media related to new Monsterverse and Monarch I'm aware of is Godzilla: Awakening comic but I assume that isn't it.

Here's a snapshot from the [Wiki](https://wikizilla.org/wiki/Monarch):

[image]

Comment: https://www.monarchsciences.com/

Comment: http://www.godzilla-movies.com/topic/45818